# can i add a pre-set subject line in email links

Tags: email, hyperlink

I've recently figured out that I can add email links to a SharePoint page. I was wondering if it's possible to add a default subject line or body text?

Comment: This is so clever, thank you. I am finding though that when you click on the email link, its showing the % signs in the email subject header. Is there anyway to have it so they show as spaces? I can get the subject to show but if I try at the &body= bit, it doesn't like it at all. Could I be doing something wrong, or does Sharepoint just not like it? Thanks Jen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `?subject=` at the **end of the mailto link** and then add the subject line, replacing spaces with `%20`. So if you want an email link to go to person@company.com with a subject line that says "this is important", you would format the link as follows:

```
mailto:person@company.com?subject=this%20is%20important
```

you can also add body text by appending `&body=` and following the above formatting.

Reference the following: https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cos-pages-editor/how-do-i-create-a-mailto-link